# npm install & build Error on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webserver

Why am I getting the following error when executing a npm install on a nodejs server?

```
nodejs@node69107 ~ $ ls
log  nodejs.lock  package-lock.json  ROOT
nodejs@node69107 ~ $ ls ROOT
esg  index.html  node_modules  package.json  package-lock.json  README.md  server.js  src
nodejs@node69107 ~ $ npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/jelastic/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/jelastic/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jelastic/.npm/_logs/2021-07-22T12_17_18_911Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try `cd ROOT` and then `npm install`

Comment: Because the package file is in ROOT, not your current directory. Either change directory or specify the `--prefix` for the installation.